# Immutable library functions in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm working with Immutable and react and today I faced something quite strange.

I've a container parsing data to a component, as usual, but when I check the props in the component, I can see functions from Immutable... and I don't know the reason.

I've been checking the data sent from the container and it looks good, but When it arrives to the components I've this:

```
@@__IMMUTABLE_ITERABLE__@@:true
@@__IMMUTABLE_KEYED__@@:true
@@__IMMUTABLE_MAP__@@:true
asImmutable: ƒ()
asMutable: ƒ()
bootstrapActions: {fetchEvents: ƒ, fetchSports: ƒ, fetchMyevents: ƒ, fetchInfo: ƒ}
butLast:ƒ ()
chain:ƒ (mapper, context)
channelImgUrl:"/logo"
children: null
clear:ƒ ()
concat:ƒ ()
contains:ƒ (searchValue)
count:ƒ (predicate, context)
countBy:ƒ (grouper, context)
delete:ƒ (k)
deleteIn:ƒ (keyPath)
```

There are still more props but it is too big..., as you can see, I've some of my props (bootstrapActions and channelImgUrl) but all the rest are "injected" somehow somewhere.

As requested, find here the container SportcenterDetailsContainer code that points to the component :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => { 

 const event = getEventById(state, ownProps)

  const eventMatchid = getEventByMatchId(getEventById)(state, ownProps)

  const info = getDefaultCatalog(state, ownProps)

  const tenantIcon = getInfoIcon(state)

  // get setting for the stream protocol that should be used
  const userModel = getUserInfo(state)

  const streamProtocol = userModel.get('settings') && userModel.get('settings').get('sportcenter.streamProtocol')

  // get valid detail buttons
  let myEventsTemporaryLabel = getMyEventsButtonTemporaryLabel(state, ownProps)

  // TODO (possible performance improvement) cache detailbuttons in order to avoid creating a new ref every time
  let detailButtons = getDetailButtons(event, info, eventMatchid, myEventsTemporaryLabel, streamProtocol)

  // XXX: Make sure there is always at least one button, otherwise the UI is broken.
  if (!detailButtons || detailButtons.isEmpty()) {
    detailButtons = loadingButtonList
  }

  let title, divisionName, description, channelImgUrl, sportName, eventDate, fromToTime, moreSports, sportId, imgUrl, eventExpired

  if (event) {
    title = event.get('title')
    divisionName = event.getIn(['division', 'name'])
    description = event.get('description')
    channelImgUrl = event.get('channelImgUrl')
    sportName = event.getIn(['sport', 'name'])
    eventDate = event.get('date')
    fromToTime = event.get('fromToTime')
    moreSports = sportName && translate('MORE') + ' ' + sportName
    sportId = event.getIn(['sport', 'id'])
    imgUrl = event.get('imgUrl')

    const endTime = event.getIn(['broadcastPeriod', 'end']) ? Date.parse(event.getIn(['broadcastPeriod', 'end'])) : undefined

    if (Date.now() > endTime) {
      // The event has already expired.
      eventExpired = true
    }
  }

  const relatedEvents = getRelatedEventsByEvent(state, ownProps)

  return {
    relatedEvents,
    imgUrl,
    title,
    detailButtons,
    tenantIcon,
    divisionName,
    description,
    channelImgUrl,
    sportId,
    sportName,
    eventDate,
    fromToTime,
    eventExpired,
    moreSports,
    disableOpenMenu: true
  }
}
/* define the automatically dispatched actions as part of this.props */
const mapActionCreators = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  })

/* define inital actions when route becomes active */
function bootstrap () {
  return Promise.all([this.props.bootstrapActions.fetchEvents(),
    this.props.bootstrapActions.fetchSports(),
    this.props.bootstrapActions.fetchMyevents(),
    this.props.bootstrapActions.fetchInfo()])
}

/* connect the container to redux for dynamic props */
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators)(
    KeyhandlingWrapper(SportcenterDetails, bootstrap)
)
```

As I said, at the end of the mapStateToProps I checked what I was sending and it was fine, but when I check the props in my functional component, I can see all this data injected.

Comment: Please edit the post and show the code of the container so we will be able to see the props sent to the component?

Comment: Done, there are some calls to functions but they return plain objects

Comment: I meant show us the component not the mapStateToProps because maybe you are passing unwanted props over there by mistake.

Comment: The component is the one that receive the props, is a functional component, so I think that there we won't be able to see anything.
In the container we don't have any component, we parse directly the component to the container. Sportcenterdetailscontainer is the container and sportcenterdetails is the component

Comment: Its hard to say from this code, however, from my experience, it seems like your object is 'corrupted' with ImmutableJs Map & native Js object. One way is to review the props via the Redux devTools to see the state of the props being passed to the component.

Comment: Oh, nice tip, I'll check it!

Comment: Ok, the main issue was that the formatter for chrome was not working properly...